# Why Pylint is too slow while pep8 just takes a second to check the same code?

Tags: performance, pylint

I do not understand why pylint takes about 5 minutes to check my code, where pep8 takes only 1 sec.

I use Mac and I have `pylint 1.8.4` installed through `conda install -c conda-forge pylint`. Pylint is very slow either I use Terminal or the *Spyder* editor. I tried creating a config file `.pylintrc` but it didn't make a difference to the speed.

How can I accelerate the Pylint speed? Thank you.

Comment: This Pylint issue might be relevant:  [Pylint slow when run on script with pandas #2198](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2198)

Answer (score 9):

You can speed up `pylint` by spawning multiple processes and checking files in parallel. This functionality is exposed via the `-j` command-line parameter. If the provided number is `0`, then the total number of CPUs will be autodetected and used. From the output of `pylint --help`:

```
-j <n-processes>, --jobs=<n-processes>
    Use multiple processes to speed up Pylint. Specifying
    0 will auto-detect the number of processors available
    to use. [current: 1]
```

Comment: I'm not finding this actually changing the performance.

Comment: I moved to `ruff`, it's much much faster

Comment: I can confirm no significant speedup (<10%) for my project with around 25 py files and using 12 CPU's. That's disappointing...

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](https://rtpg.co/2020/11/13/profiling-pylint.html) gives a good performance analysis.
`pylint` analyzes every line of code for two things:

1. the code itself, obviously,
2. the message control, also called [pragma](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/message_control.html#block-disables), i.e. comments like `# pylint: disable=line-too-long`.

While pragmas are a nice feature to add linter exceptions, they come to the expense of a more complex logic.
Moreover, this features triggers additional checks when the line is too long, and when the module contains too many lines ([source code as of Jan. 2023](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/6b427a9189c86143bc361c56393e028ad3e5c3e1/pylint/checkers/format.py#L448)).

While I can fix my code, I cannot control the libraries I import.
For instance, pandas has modules of [12k lines](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.3/pandas/core/frame.py).

**My workaround** - Increase the `max-line-length` and `max-module-lines` parameters in `.pylintrc`, e.g. to 200 and 15000.
No miracle here, but a visible improvement (not measured).

**Note** - Using `-j` or setting `jobs` does not work for me because it is used to [process *modules* in parallel](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/usage/run.html#parallel-execution).
It does not accelerate the linting of a single file, and syntastic calls the pylint on the current file only.

Answer (score 1):

Some version of Pylint have performance problems, try rolling back a version or rolling forward to a newer version.

Smaller code bases seem to lint faster than larger ones, although I don't have any numbers to back that up.

Disable any rules that you don't plan to fix anyway- at one time spell checking in pylint was a problem.

Try a different tool - PyCharm's inspections covers a lot of similar ground and for the most part in my experience hasn't had the performance problems of pylint.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try your proposed solutions and will let you know which one could solve the speed problem I'm facing.

Comment: > PyCharm's inspections
How are you supposed to run it in CI? Is it even a thing?

Comment: @validname - Looks technically possible now:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-code-inspector.html I didn't check if there are licensing challenges (probably are)